# Swift ERROR- [__NSCFData gotoShowChannel11] When i create button in Delegate and add view on tabbar

Tags: swift, button, ios8

I am gating my problem in IOS 8 but my code working in IOS 9 . I have create one **Transparent button** and add subview in Tabbar method. The Problem is button event not working when tabar load second time and this is problem in IOS 8 , but its working good in ISO 9. Here is my code

**Delegate**

```
var button_ofTabbar = UIButton();
     //var button_ofTabbar:UIButton!;

    //UIButton();= UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
```

**In Tabbar**

```
class tabbar: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {




    //let button_ofTabbar   = UIButton();

    var delegate1: AppDelegate!
     let aDataBase : databaseinit = databaseinit()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 242/255.0, green: 134/255.0, blue: 55/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.delegate=self;
         delegate1 = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate



        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        if(delegate1.tag_jive_channel_tab == 0)
        {
           //  delegate1.button_ofTabbar.removeFromSuperview();
           // delegate1.button_ofTabbar.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)


            delegate1.button_ofTabbar.hidden = false;
            let widthofbtn:CGFloat = self.tabBar.frame.size.width/5;

        delegate1.button_ofTabbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tabBar.frame.origin.y, widthofbtn, self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
            delegate1.button_ofTabbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()//clearColor()

           //delegate1.button_ofTabbar = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        delegate1.button_ofTabbar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()//clearColor()
        delegate1.button_ofTabbar.addTarget(self, action: "gotoShowChannel11", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(delegate1.button_ofTabbar);


        }

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

       }
func gotoShowChannel11() {

        delegate1.button_ofTabbar.hidden = true;
        //orangeColor tabbar
        //self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor();
        delegate1.tag_jive_channel_tab = 1;

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("update_tabbar", object: nil,
            userInfo: nil);

            //UIColor(red: 146/255.0, green: 146/255.0, blue: 146/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

When i use this line `delegate1.button_ofTabbar = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)` then my button is not show custom/System in both

i am also try this `func gotoShowChannel11(sender: UIButton!)`
Please help me . i am stuck in IOS 8 Problem .  and Error is 
**ERROR- [__NSCFData gotoShowChannel11]**
Please any one Help me .
Now I have found another solution . Thankyou .

Comment: That `delegate1.button_ofTabbar` stuff looks incredibly brittle and likely to break.  What are you trying to do?  Have the "`gotoShowChannel11:`" function be called whenever a certain button in the tab bar controller is touched?